# Should we change the default suggested tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, new-users

The "Ask Question" form currently suggests tags in the placeholder text: [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology). I would **guess** that these are the most common tags used.

[image: Placeholder for tags, showing default suggestion]

However, are they the **most useful** examples to offer? I think we should probably offer tags which are likely to produce the most improvement in a question. The questions with the greatest likelihood for improvement are (I think) those whose authors should read the help available on [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) and [prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions). Perhaps we could also offer [tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenses).

I certainly don't think that [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) or [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) should be offered **at all.**

If we had the opportunity to change this helper text, what tags would you like to see here? Please add **one per answer,** and upvote/downvote according to how **suitable for question askers** you feel the suggestion would be. [Suggesting a tag in an answer should be assessed as a single upvote by the author.]

Note that you can get a tag to appear in an answer and be clickable by using the syntax `[tag:etymology]` to get [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology).

Comment: I would keep [tag:word-choice], the explanation is short and it tells the author to use SWR if they don't know the word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please add that as an answer. Your answer could include your justification for using that tag.

Answer (score 6):

[single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)

> This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.  Click on "Info" or "View Tag" and "Learn more ..." for more information. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.

(We should probably edit that excerpt for the new tag display)

Answer (score 5):

I would keep [word-choice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice), the explanation is short and it tells the author to use SWR if they don't know the word they're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[tenses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tenses)

> A set of forms taken by a verb to indicate the time and/or completeness and continuance of the action in relation to the time of the utterance.

Answer (score 2):

[prepositions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions)

> Prepositions are function words like "to", "over", "through", "in". The meaning of a sentence can be dramatically altered by choosing the wrong preposition. Questions need to include enough information for the intended meaning to be deduced.